# Is there a time limit to get your items out of pick-only stash tabs?

Tags: path-of-exile

When a league ends, the characters and the stash tabs are merged in the parent league (either SC/HC). The stash tabs are then made "pick-only", i.e. a person cannot put anything in those tabs, only take away, and they disappear when empty.

Is there a time limit after which they will disappear even if there are items into them?

Comment: the system told me that the title is "opinion-based". why?

Comment: I still have remove-only tabs from years ago. So don't worry about your items disappearing any time soon :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On [the Official PoE Wiki](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Stash#Remove-only_Tabs) it says that

> Tabs from the temporary league will appear as remove-only tabs in the parent league. **These tabs will remain indefinitely**, but items cannot be put into them, even items which started out in that tab. Once a remove-only tab has been emptied, it will disappear.